# How to setup a RadioButton set within templates?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, radio-button

I've the following scenario: I have a predefined, already initialized **Dictionary** structure. The elements of this dictionary are displayed through a **ListBox**. In each row, there is two **TextBoxes** and a **RadioButton**, that makes reference to the Country structure variable inside the dictionary. When I click in a radiobutton, I save the country name in the preferences, and when I reload the view, the saved option is restored.
My code is as follows:

In .XAML file:

```
<ListBox Height="Auto" Margin="0, 0, 0, 16" x:Name="CountryCodeSelect_countrylist">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="CountryCodeSelect_listfields" Margin="16" Height="64" Width="432" Background="#F2F2F2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="16,0,0,0"
                    Text="{Binding Key}"
                    Foreground="Black"
                    FontSize="24"
                    FontWeight="Black"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="16,0,8,0"
                    Text="{Binding Value.CountryCode}"
                    Foreground="Black"
                    FontSize="24"
                    FontWeight="Black"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <RadioButton
                    Margin="0,0,24,0"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource radioBoolToIntConverter}, ConverterParameter=Value.CountryName}"
                    GroupName="CountryCodeSelect_countries"
                    DataContext="{Binding Value.CountryName}"
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Click="RadioButton_Click" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And my model .CS file:

```
public Dictionary<string, Country> countries = new Dictionary<string, Country>() {
    { "Afghanistan", new Country("Afghanistan", ".com", 93, false) },
    { "Albania", new Country("Albania", ".com", 355, false) },
    { "Algeria", new Country("Algeria", ".com", 213, false) },
    . . .
    . . .
    . .
    .
}


public CountryCodeSelect() {
    InitializeComponent();
    // reload previous saved value
    string cn = Persistence.load_countryName();
    if (cn != null) {
        Country c;
        countries.TryGetValue(cn, out c);
        c.Checked = true;
        countries.Remove(c.CountryName);
        countries.Add(c.CountryName, c);
    }
    CountryCodeSelect_countrylist.ItemsSource = countries;
}

private int _IsChecked;
public int IsChecked { get { return _IsChecked; } set { _IsChecked = value; } }
```

My issue/question is: **how can I initialize the radio button as "checked"?** The behavior that I've reached with this code is the full list, with the country names showed, and the variables setuped. But none of my radio buttons are showed as checked. I'm wondering if I need to "refreshed" the page, but if so, how can I do it?